# Use regex to split String

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a String using regex with Java.
The string looks like this: `{'tata','toto','titi'}`
But `{}` describes the order of the preceding liberal, so it doesn't work for me.

What regex should I use to get this result :

```
tata
toto
titi
```

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far?

Comment: \d{X} means in regex that it occurs X times. how to ignore the braces

Comment: Are you trying to parse an existing data-interchange format? If so there may be a better solution than regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
String str = "{'tata','toto','titi'}";
String[] arr = str.split("[{},']+");
//=> tata, toto, titi
```

There is no need to escape `{` or `}` inside character class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\` to disable the special meaning of any character in a regex.

Since `\` itself has a special meaning in a `String` you will need to duplicate it if you specify your regex directly in a String literal in java. So replace `"{something}"` with `\\{something\\}"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "{'tata','toto','titi'}"
a = a.replace("{'", ""); // get rid of opening bracket and singlequote
a = a.replace("'}", ""); // get rid of ending bracket and singlequote
String[] b = a.split("','"); // split on commas surrounded by singlequotes
```

This should give you an array of just the words you want. I guess it's not specifically regex, but it should do the right thing anyway.

Comment: Totally forgot about replace not changing the original string. Thanks for setting me straight, whoever you were.